# Select class within a class in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My html has two classes, 'relevant' and 'a'. I'm wondering how to select < p > elements that are part of both classes. Not just one or the other, both at the same time. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my html:

```
<h1>Hi</h1>
    <h2 class="important">Hi again</h2>
    <p class="a">Random unattached paragraph</p>


    <div class="relevant">
        <p class="a">first</p>
        <p class="a">second</p>
        <p>third</p>
        <p>fourth</p>
        <p class="a">fifth</p>
        <p class="a">sixth</p>
    </div>
```

So in this example, I'd like to select only the 'first', 'second', 'fifth', and 'sixth' < p>'s because they fall into both classes at the same time.

I've tried selecting both on the same css line but it doesn't select anything:

```
.a.relevant{
color: red;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `.a.relevant` selects a single element which has both classes.  For context you need a space as in @sneeky answer

Comment: What you're really asking is how to apply styling to an `.a` only when it is a child of `.relevant`. Your code works for a single element that has both classes (`class="a relevant"`). Sneeky's answer is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
.relevant .a {
    color: red;
}
```

This is the way for selecting .a in an element with the class relevant

Answer (score 5):

```
.relevant .a {
  color: red;
}
```

This targets all elements of class `a` that are within elements of class `relevant`.

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/pezeq/1/edit

Your previous rule (`.a.relevant`) would select all elements that **themselves** have **both** the class `a` and the class `relevant`.

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/pezeq/2/edit